# How can adding warnings to a published API break existing clients

Tags: java, api, warnings

I was reading the Effective Java book and found the following there in **Item 7:
Avoid finalizers** section:

> The four classes cited as examples of the explicit termination method pattern
>   (FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, Timer, and Connection) have finalizers
>   that serve as safety nets in case their termination methods aren’t called. Unfortunately these finalizers do not log warnings. **Such warnings generally can’t be
>   added after an API is published, as it would appear to break existing clients.**

My question is how? The only way I can imagine this should happen is if clients are parsing the java process's output and these extra warnings can somehow break their parsing.

Is there a different reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I know why. The book says:

> it would **appear** to break existing clients

I think what is implied here is that clients that were running fine until now will suddenly start giving warning messages and that too at random times as the warnings are from a finalizer method. That would make it seem as if something has gone wrong with the client.

The key here is the "appear" word. I can't think of a case where the client logic will actually break due to this, just appear to break.